ros2_control hardware interface: where in the lifecycle should I wait for hardware initialization?
I am trying to understand how the hardware interface lifecycle should interact with actual hardware initialization, and it's hard to figure out - the documentation specifies what I should do on the software side, but it's less clear on the hardware side. My primary question is - when it takes time for the hardware to come online (and until it's fully online, I cannot execute the read/write commands), where in the hardware interface would it be OK to wait, without something else becoming impatient and timing out? So far, the best I was able to figure out is to just have NaNs for all the joints until the hardware is ready, and this seems to have the least of the bad side-effects, but still causes a lot of warnings...
Edited to add: I am using ros2_control with MoveIt2, and one of the issues is that if I pause things to wait for the robot to come online, then a bunch of things time out and die. E.g. with a large delay in on_configure, I get:
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1716389355.529942312] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1716389355.605073022] [spawner_robot_controller]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' services to be available
[...]
[spawner-6] [ERROR] [1716389369.632298751] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-5] [ERROR] [1716389369.711568868] [spawner_robot_controller]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-6]: process has died [pid 206778, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/iron/lib/controller_manager/spawner --controller-manager-timeout 20 joint_state_broadcaster --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-5]: process has died [pid 206776, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/iron/lib/controller_manager/spawner --controller-manager-timeout 20 robot_controller --ros-args'].


See our tutorial here:
Usually you would do this in the on_configure() method.

thanks I tried that, but then MoveIt nodes time out and die - see the "edited to add" part I've added. I guess I could always change the --controller-manager-timeout argument to be very large to account for the slowest it might take for the robot to be powered up (even if somebody is powering it up manually) - is that the best option here?

The errors do not come from moveit but from the ros2_control spawners.
You can use the timeout as you already have found, or you use the lifecycle features of the controllers and configure+activate them later instead of spawning everything from a single launch file. Like we do here with JTC.

You can even control the lifecycle of the hardware components, see hardware_components_initial_state parameter in the docs.
